# Update existing app service with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

in my Azure account a have some resources. Resource groups, app services, storage accounts...
I've created these resources by using the Azure portal or Powershell.
Then i've written a terraform script to add *other* resources and **update** some of the existing ones. In particular i'm interested in updating the app service. I want to add some settings and a managed identity to it.
What happens is that terraform says: "look, there is already an app service with the name you specified".
I tried to use "terraform import" to bind the existing app service to my terrafom state file, but doing so i loose the settings that i've put in the terraform file.

How can i solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`terraform import` is the way to go. If you have any existing settings in your file: Just remove them until you have fully imported the app service.

Full tutorial - with a resource group instead of an app service, but the principle is the same:
https://azurecitadel.com/automation/terraform/lab6/#lab-importing-resources

- Create a resource group:

```
Grab the ID for the azure resource: id=$(az group show --name deleteme --query id --output tsv)
```

Create an empty stanza for the resource in a new import.tf file

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "deleteme" {}
```

- Run the import command:

```
terraform import azurerm_resource_group.deleteme $id
terraform-labs$ terraform import azurerm_resource_group.deleteme $id
Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...
azurerm_resource_group.deleteme: Importing from ID "/subscriptions/2d31be49-d999-4415-bb65-8aec2c90ba62/resourceGroups/deleteme"...
azurerm_resource_group.deleteme: Import complete!
  Imported azurerm_resource_group (ID: /subscriptions/2d31be49-d999-4415-bb65-8aec2c90ba62/resourceGroups/deleteme)
azurerm_resource_group.deleteme: Refreshing state... (ID: /subscriptions/2d31be49-d999-4415-bb65-8aec2c90ba62/resourceGroups/deleteme)

Import successful!

The resources that were imported are shown above. These resources are now in
your Terraform state and will henceforth be managed by Terraform.
```

- Run `terraform plan` and you should see some errors as our block is not populated
- Run `terraform state show azurerm_resource_group.deleteme`

```
id       = /subscriptions/2d31be49-d999-4415-bb65-8aec2c90ba62/resourceGroups/deleteme
location = westeurope
name     = deleteme
tags.%   = 0
```

- Add in the name argument, and the location using the loc variable
- Rerun terraform plan and it should show no errors and no planned changes
- The resource is now fully imported and safely under the control of Terraform.

Comment: Ok it worked, thank you. I just think that is very tedious. What if i have already a lot of resources in Azure? I have to apply this approach for each single existing resource...

Comment: I agree... terraform itself says so: *"While this may seem tedious, it still gives Terraform users an avenue for importing existing resources. A future version of Terraform will fully generate configuration, significantly simplifying this process."*

Comment: @AlexAIT How can add the import step in azure develops pipe line?