# data vs resource in Terraform for Azure App Service Plan

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am working on Terraform script for Azure. Currently  App Service Plan is declared as data. Now i need to add Scaleout Rules. Should i create  App Service Plan as data or convert it to 'resource' and add scaleout rules?

```
data "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  name = "search-app-service-plan"
  resource_group_name = "search-service"
}
```

Comment: You don’t need to try any of the above methods. Use `terraform import` to import the `app service Plan` resource into the state file & then change it in the way you want.

Comment: App Service Plan was create through Terraform only so 'data' is declared

Comment: Please add the code you are currently using, without it it's only guesswork.

Comment: refer link: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/app_service_plan      data "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "search-app-service-plan"
  resource_group_name = "search-service"
}  this is how App service plan is defined in my terraform code currently

Comment: That's all the code you have?

Comment: "convert it to 'resource' and add scaleout rules" yes, and you would also need to import it after declaring. Note that https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/service_plan does not seem to have an argument or block for adding scaleout rules though.

Comment: Could you please refer this [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58039351/update-existing-app-service-with-terraform)

Answer (score 1):

data is added to access information about an existing resource.

In case your app service plan resource is not created via terraform, you need to import existing infrastructure. This allows you take resources you've created by some other means and bring it under Terraform management.

And then you can just add the resource app service block with everything you needed including the scale out rules and running script then would be ok.